# Failed to initialize detector. Input tensor has type kTfliteFloat32 ML Kit

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite, darknet, google-mlkit, yolov4

I'd like to know if it is possible to implement a darknet model (yolov4-tiny) converted to .tflite in android studio with  ML Kit. I've tried to use this repository: https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart , but when I replace to my custom object detection model, application returns this error: *Failed to process. Error: Failed to initialize detector. Input tensor has type kTfliteFloat32: it requires specifying NormalizationOptions metadata to preprocess input images. Cause:null.*
Could you give me an advice?, please. I'm trying to count objects in real time, I think ML kit is the only way to track and count objects without repeat. Thank you in advance.

Comment: MLKit sample application requires the additional metadata information to proceed the tasks. Please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata#model_with_metadata_format for filling up the necessary metadata for your model.

Comment: Thank you, I followed the steps to add metadata. However when I run: populator.load_metadata_buffer(metadata_buf), I got this this error: The number of output tensors (2) should match the number of output tensor metadata (1)

Comment: According to the error message, it seems like your TFLite graph has two output tensors but you only provide only one output tensor metadata information. Please add two output tensor metadata information while adding the metadata.

Comment: I tried it, but I got this error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 4 bytes.

Comment: By the way, do you know if it is possible to activate tracking in tensorflow lite repository for android? I've read new updates doesn't allow object tracking. This is the reason why I'm trying to use Ml Kit.

Comment: ML kit is also using TensorFlow Lite, for example, https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models. Object tracking has been supported through TFLite. Please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/object_detection/overview.

Answer (score 4):

You can run this code for fixing this bug

```
from tflite_support.metadata_writers import object_detector
from tflite_support.metadata_writers import writer_utils
from tflite_support import metadata
ObjectDetectorWriter = object_detector.MetadataWriter
_MODEL_PATH = "yolo_without_metadata.tflite"
# Task Library expects label files that are in the same format as the one below.
_LABEL_FILE = "labelmap.txt"
_SAVE_TO_PATH = "yolo_with_metadata.tflite"
# Normalization parameters is required when reprocessing the image. It is
# optional if the image pixel values are in range of [0, 255] and the input
# tensor is quantized to uint8. See the introduction for normalization and
# quantization parameters below for more details.
# https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata#normalization_and_quantization_parameters)
_INPUT_NORM_MEAN = 127.5
_INPUT_NORM_STD = 127.5

# Create the metadata writer.
writer = ObjectDetectorWriter.create_for_inference(
    writer_utils.load_file(_MODEL_PATH), [_INPUT_NORM_MEAN], [_INPUT_NORM_STD],
    [_LABEL_FILE])

# Verify the metadata generated by metadata writer.
print(writer.get_metadata_json())

# Populate the metadata into the model.
writer_utils.save_file(writer.populate(), _SAVE_TO_PATH)
```

Comment: Can you please add more detail? How we will use this code in android?

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to use the ML Kit [Custom Object Detection and Tracking](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/custom-models/android) feature?   For that feature, the custom model supported is a classifier model, not a detector model.   You can find more details in https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/custom-models